# Python variables outside function

Tags: python

I'm trying to access the counter variable in my function, why doesn't it work and how do I resolve it?

Relevant code:

```
sum = 0
counter = 0

def newFibo(a, b) :
    if(counter > 4000000) :
        return

    c = a + b

    sum += c
    counter +=1
    newFibo(b,c)

newFibo(1,2)
print(sum)
```

error: "local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment"

Comment: Simple solution is to add a `global counter, sum` at the start of your function. The better solution is to change your function so it does not depend on *and modify* a global variable.

Comment: Psst - I can sense this is for that one Project Euler question. As a quick hint: *every third* Fibonacci number is even - do you see why? Can you prove it?

Answer (score 1):

In Python, if you want to *modify* a global variable inside a function, you have to declare it as `global` inside the function:

```
 def newFibo(a, b) :
    global counter, sum
    ..............
```

Note that you don't need it if the variable is only read inside the function but not modified.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the keyword `global` to tell python that a variable is outside the current function.

So, basically, add `global sum, counter` right after `def newFibo(a, b):`.